# Haskell: data definition and Functor class

Tags: haskell, functor

i was trying to define the data type Set but i have problems when i try to instantiate the functor class.

This is my code:

```
data Set a where
    Empty :: Eq a => Set a
    Add   :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Set a

instance Functor Set where
    fmap = setMap

setMap :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a->b) -> Set a -> Set b 
setMap f Empty = Empty
setMap f (Add x set) = Add (f x) $ setMap f set
```

And this is what the compiler says:

```
    No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘setMap’
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            fmap :: (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
```

Why isn't the constraint in the setMap definition enough? Or, if it is, why is it wrong?

Comment: It is enough, but you have to add that to the signature of `Functor` as well, since otherwise the constraints are *not* satisfied. And this will cause problems since a `Functor` is a typeclass that specifies that you are allowed to `fmap` from any `a` to any `b`.

Comment: The point is: say I want to use `fmap`, then I assume that it has signature `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, not that there are extra constraints. So these are not "*ad hoc*" functions where based on `f` there are extra type constraints.

Comment: Put another way, `fmap f` has to work for *all* types that `Set` might create, not just the ones that support equality. It's the difference between `Set a` and `Eq a => Set a`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How should add the constraint to the Functor? I mean, do i have to create a more specific kind of functor?

Comment: @user7363624: here that will be impossible, since `a` and `b` are not part of the `Functor` class. Only if you could define somthing like `Functor (Set a b)`, you could have written `instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Functor (Set a b)`.

Comment: It is well-known that data structures like `Set a` which require additional constraints on `a` (e.g. `Eq` or `Ord`) can not be members of the `Functor` typeclass. Simply put, the `Functor` class requires no constraints at all. We could define a generalization of that class to consider constraints as well, but it won't be a `Functor` anyway.

Comment: So i guess i should give up on the functor part. I will just use my setMap instead of fmap, not that it really matters since i was just trying out a few things. Thank you both for your answers. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

A functor is a pair of functions: a type constructor `f` that maps one type to another, and a function `fmap` that maps functions of type `a -> b` to functions of type `f a -> f b`. There are *no* restrictions on what `a` and `b` are; both `f` and `fmap` need to work for all types.

`Set` qualifies as the type constructor; given any type `a`, it returns a new type `Set a`.

`setMap`, however, does *not* work with any two types `a` and `b`; it only works with types `Eq a => a` and `Eq b => b`.

So, the pair `Set`/`setMap` is *almost*, but not quite, a functor from **Hask** to **Hask** (or an endofunctor on **Hask**), which is what the `Functor` type class represents.  (**Hask** is the somewhat-controversial category defined as the class of all Haskell types and the functions defined on those types.)

---

However, one could define a subcategory of **Hask** called **HaskEq**, whose objects would be all the Haskell types with an `Eq` instance. Then `Set`/`setMap` would be a endofunctor on **HaskEq**, since `setMap` would be valid for any type in **HaskEq**. There's no easy way to represent **HaskEq** in Haskell, although **Hask** is trivial, as shown in [`Control.Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/Control.Category.html):

```
class Category a where
    id :: cat a a
    (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c

-- Hask
instance Category (->) where
    id = GHC.Base.id
    (.) = (GHC.Base..)
```

But you could define your own type class to represent such endofunctors:

```
class EqFunctor f where
    eqfmap :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance EqFunctor Set where
    eqfmap = setMap
```